# How to find out If scene is fully rendered. (loaded all textures,etc)

Tags: javascript, three.js, render, loaded

I am doing project in [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) and I have in scene maybe 300 objects, with 30 sprites, some of them put me in loading to console warning about image is not power of two and they are resizing (one img resize maybe 0.1 sec (aprox)). My scene is fully loaded maybe in 5 second (all sprites animation is running and are visible, fps is ok, etc).
Is there in Three js any script to say all objects are fully loaded (rendered in scene), or if all objects are resized correctly, or something what would help me to find out correct time? Because I dont want to people see continuously objects loading.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Take a look at [`THREE.LoadingManager()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/loaders/managers/LoadingManager).

Comment: thanks, it helps me